# How To Make User Input Match Using JavaScript for Form Validation

Tags: html, forms, validation, youtube-api

I have seen similar questions but they were not asked the same way I want to ask my question.

How can I use javascript to make sure that the email a user provides matches with the email that I want them to provide before the form gets submitted after the user hits the submit button.

**Elaboration:**

The correct email address is **badmansmo@gmail.com**.

My form input placeholder shows **b.........o@.....com** as a hint.

If the user inputs any email that does not match with **badmansmo@gmail.com**
I want them to get an error message and the form should not be submitted.

How can I do this with javascript?

See my code below.

```html
   <form action='' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class='item'>
          
          <p><b><span style="color: red;">Email Address</span></b><span class='required'>*</span></p>
         
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ba******o@***.com" required=''/>
           
       </div>
<div class='question'>
          <center><p>Privacy Policy<span class='required'>*</span></p></center>
          <div class='question-answer checkbox-item'>
            <div>
              
              <center><label class='check' for='check_1'><span>By submitting this form you agree to the terms of service <a href='https://www.google.com/p/privacy-policy.html' target="_blank">privacy policy.</a></span></label></center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='btn-block'>
         <center> <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Submit</button></center>
      
      </div></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, you need to add and change a few things so it would work.

First, add an 'id' attribute to the email input field like this (so we can link the form to the javascript code later on):

```
input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ba******o@***.com" required='' id="email"/>
```

Then, add the following script at the beginning of the page (between the  and the  tags). This script compares the entered email and shows a message if they are not matching.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_email()
{
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    
    if(email.localeCompare("badmansmo@gmail.com")) {
        alert("ERROR. Email does not match.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Finally, add the 'onsubmit' attribute to the  tag like this (if the function that checks the email returns false, then the form won't be sent):

```
<form action='' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return check_email();">
```

I hope this works for you :)